# creating xml file with xml schema in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I try to generate a number of xml file which is containing the schema.I use jaxb to make xml file from schema but i did not able to add schema with in this xml.My desired file looks like

```
<transaction>
  <xs:schema id="transaction" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="transaction" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="id">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="in" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="sn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="book" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="data">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="productData">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <id>
    <in>abcd</in>
    <sn>1234567</sn>
    <book>computer</book>
    <author>klen</author>
  </id>
  <data>
    <dateTime>2011-06-24T17:08:36.3727674+05:30</dateTime>
    <key>Err</key>
  </data>
</transaction>
```

but till now i am able to generate xml file look like

```
<transaction>
      <id>
        <in>abcd</in>
        <sn>1234567</sn>
        <book>computer</book>
        <author>klen</author>
      </id>
      <data>
        <dateTime>2011-06-24T17:08:36.3727674+05:30</dateTime>
        <key>Err</key>
      </data>
</transaction>
```

I didn't understand how to add this schema under  node.is there any way to add this schema under  node using jaxb in java.Main part of my code is like

```
                    transaction.getIdOrDataOrProductData().add(id);
                    transaction.getIdOrDataOrProductData().add(data);
                    transaction.getIdOrDataOrProductData().add(productdata);
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transaction.class);
                    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true);
                    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT,true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(transaction, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(transaction, System.out);
```

is there any way to change the code by which i can add schema with xml file.
our application actually check the file structure if it is not look like my given example then it will be deleted,So i should to follow this structure by which it will update the database.Now my question is that how can I add this my xml file using jaxb.

using C# .NET platform it is possible to generate xml file with schema.is it possible in java.

Comment: @Patrice Matignon can you tell me how i send this schema object as well as marshalling the schema by which I can generate the xml file with schema.

Comment: @Patrice Matignon I am sorry to say that it is not clear for me can you describe it briefly actually I am new in java so I cannot understand your suggestion.Actually I did not change my schema,and another thing is that how I convert xslt to xml with schema.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your schema that says that the schema itself should be added to the instance document.

You would need something like:

```
<xs:element name="transaction" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <!-- Adding an element that can supports the schema definition -->
      <xs:element ref="xs:schema" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <!-- and from here on, what you already have : -->
      <xs:element name="id">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="in" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="sn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="book" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
           </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
       ...
```

And then you'd have to insert the schema into your transaction JAXB object for it to show up in your instance document.

Now, I would like to know more about your use case: are you sure you need to do this ? 
The document itself (the transaction XML) could simply specify the schema it conforms to, and even specify a location e.g. :

```
 <transaction xmlns="urn:mytransactionschema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/transaction.xsd" >
```

This should give consumers of your instance document the ability to validate the XML better than by including it in the instance doc.

Comment: our application actually check the file structure if it is not look like my given example then it will be deleted,So i should to follow this structure by which it will update the database.Now my question is that how can I add this my xml file using jaxb.

Comment: can you tell me how i send this schema object as well as marshalling the schema by which I can generate the xml file with schema.

Comment: The issue is that adding the schema itself in the instance document makes the latter fail the validation against the former that's plain wrong possibly). That's why your JAXB objects won't have the API to do it out of the box. I assume you can't change the schema anyway since there is an app that consumes it (and that you can't change by yourself). I would use XSLT one way or another to 'inject' your (static) schema into your marshalled document (there are quite a few posts on this site that will help you achieve that).

Comment: but schema with xml file generation can be possible with C# .net platform.So is it possible in java.

Comment: I am sorry to say that it is not clear for me can you describe it briefly actually I am new in java so I cannot understand your suggestion.Actually I did not change my schema,and another thing is that how I convert xslt to xml with schema.please give me some reply.

Answer (score 0):

I know using C# in .NET platform you can do this thing, xml file with schema definition can be possible.  I think in java it is not possible.